# iohook module keyCode is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, keycode

I am using Node js [iohook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook) module to check if a key was pressed do some action. Here's the code:

```
    let ioHook = require('iohook');


    for (let i = 1; i < commandHistory.length; ++i) {
        ioHook.on('keydown', event => {
            if (event.keyCode === 38 || event.which === 38) {
                command = commandHistory[i - 1];
                console.log("Command:", command);
            }
            console.log("Event:", event);
        });
    }

    ioHook.start();
```

The problem is it does not display the first console log, I think because I wrote if statement  in a wrong way, i.e.

```
if (event.keyCode === 38 || event.which === 38) {...}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: event.keyCode, I think it should be event.keycode

Comment: it did not help, same problem @wut-excel